# Why are my variables undefined when switching views?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the wall of code.  I tried to simplify it as much as possible.  My console output is at the bottom.  I have a two view page.  In order to promote code modularity my page structure is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/view1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/view2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <style>
            #view2 { display: none; }
            #view3 { display: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="view1" class="box">
            <div>View1</div>
            <button class="btn-show2">View2</button>
            <button class="btn-show3">View3</button>
            <button class="btn-echo">Echo Val</button>
        </div>
        <div id="view2" class="box">
            <div>View2</div>
            <button class="btn-back">Back</button>
            <button class="btn-echo">Echo Val</button>  
        </div>
        <div id="display-out"></div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Now each "view" has it's own associated JS file as follows.  For example view1.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#view1 .btn-show2").click(function(e) {
        showContainer("view2");
    });

    handlers['btn-echo']['view1'] = function(params) {
        $("#display-out").html("View1 Custom Msg, Params : " + params + ", Active View: " + active_view + ", Random: " + Math.random());
    };

    init['view1'] = function(params) {
        console.log('view1 init routine.  Active View is ' + active_view);
    };

    destroy['view1'] = function(params) {
        console.log('view1 destroy routine.  Clean up view 1');
    };  
});
```

and view2.js is:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#view2 .btn-back").click(function(e) {
        showContainer("view1");
    });

    handlers['btn-echo']['view2'] = function(params) {
        $("#display-out").html("View2 Custom Msg, Params : " + params + ", Active View: " + active_view + ", Random: " + Math.random());
    };

    init['view2'] = function(params) {
        console.log('view2 init routine.  Active View is ' + active_view);
    };

    destroy['view2'] = function(params) {
        console.log('view2 destroy routine.  Clean up view 2');
    };  
});
```

Finally, main.js has the following structure:

```
    var active_view = null;
    var handlers = [];
    var init = [];
    var destroy = [];

    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        active_view = "view1";
        init['view1']();
    });

    handlers['btn-echo'] = [];
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-echo', function(e) {
        console.log("In initial click delegatorm active_view is " + active_view + "!!");
        if(handlers['btn-echo'] != null && typeof handlers['btn-echo'][active_view] == "function") {
            handlers['btn-echo'][active_view]("LOL");
        }
    });

    function showContainer(container_id, data) {
        $("body .box").each(function(e) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if(id == container_id) {
                active_view = container_id;
                console.log("In showContainer, active_view is now " + active_view + "!!");
                if(typeof init[id] == "function"){
                    init[id]("");
                }
                $(this).slideDown();

            }else{
                if(active_view = id && typeof destroy[id] == "function") {
                    destroy[id]();
                }
                $(this).slideUp();
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see the global active_view gets changed when the view is changed (from showContainer).  However here is the following console output:

```
view1 init routine.  Active View is view1 view1.js:11 //Start on view1
In initial click delegatorm active_view is view1!! test.html:45 //Click Echo
view1 destroy routine.  Clean up view 1 view1.js:15 //Click switch to view2
In showContainer, active_view is now view2!! test.html:56
view2 init routine.  Active View is view2 view2.js:11
In initial click delegatorm active_view is false!! //Click echo again
```

What is going on here?  Why does active_view become false?

Comment: `if(active_view = id ... ` is probably not what you meant. `active_view == id` perhaps?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? It seems like way too much unnecessary code. If you want to show hide divs on a button click it might be easier to give the divs a class of 'current' for example and then using css to show hide the divs. clicking the button moves the 'current' class to the next div

Comment: You're the best!!!  Make an answer and I'll accept.  I was hacking at this for hours.  By the way is my strategy of passing around globals and having these handler, init, and destroy functinons a good idea?

Comment: @Jackson - This was just an example.  In my real app it's more complex.  The point is I have handlers for  different events, but different views may act on them differently (each view has a "echo" button, but view1 may do something and view2 may do something else).  Some things are common to both hence I want to be able to reuse the common parts then deletate off the specific parts in the handler['action']['view_name']() function.  The init\destroy functions are good examples.  Each time a view is loaded it needs to init, but each view has differnt things to init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your CSS, you have 3 container `.box`. So it mean in your loop `showContainer`, you'll have 3 iteration.

Now, you are going to the view #2 but the last iteration is on the #3. now let see what happen (we skip the first iteration):

```
//Loop 2
var id = $(this).attr('id'); //id = 'view2'
if(id == container_id) // 'view2' == 'view2' : true
    active_view = container_id; active_view = 'view2'

//Loop 3
var id = $(this).attr('id'); //id = 'view3'
if(id == container_id) // 'view3' == 'view2' : false
else
    if(active_view = id && typeof destroy[id] == "function") // Your probleme is here
```

You see, you have a typo here, it should be `active_view == ...`. Now you are assigning a value to `active_view`

what is is doing step by step :

```
active_view = id && typeof destroy[id] == "function"; //Step 1
active_view = 'view3' && typeof destroy[id] == "function"; //Step 2
active_view = true && typeof destroy[id] == "function"; //Step 3; Since left side is true, interpret right side
active_view = typeof destroy[id] == "function"; //Step 4
active_view = typeof destroy['view3'] == "function"; //Step 5
active_view = false; //Step 6; Since the result in your log is false, I suppose destroy['view3'] is not a function
```

Comment: It was the typo that did it.  See my comment in the OP

Comment: @user47581 yes, exactly, that's what i'm *trying* to explain here.